# Multivariable partial derivative evaluation equivalencies

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

I'm calculating the multivariable Taylor series of a function and have run into this question: Is the following expression true?

$$\frac{\partial (\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}|_{x=0})}{\partial y}|_{y=0} = \frac{\partial ^2f(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}|_{x,y=0}$$

Comment: what is $dxy$??

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no. The first expression is
$$
\left(\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f_x(0,y+h)}{h} = g(y)\right) |_{y=0}\,
$$
while the second is 
$$
\left(\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f_x(x,y+h)}{h} = g(x,y)\right) |_{x=0,y=0},
$$
namely, $g(y)$ not necessarily equals $g(0,y)$